# MAC: Restore Failure: An error (32) occurred while copying image. (Broken Pipe)

Tags: mac, boot-camp

I have a disk image that I created of the Bootcamp partition on my old mac. I copied that image over to my new mac. I created a new Bootcamp partition on the new mac and am attempting to restore the image using Disk Utility. When I do that it gives me the above error. I have been unable to find any information on why I would be getting this error. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How did you create the disk image? AFAIK, Disk Utility wouldn't have preserved the NTFS filesystem if you created an image with it.

Comment: I did create it with disk utility. It verifies ok and I can mount the Image. What would be the correct way to create an image that I can transfer over and restore?

Comment: If you still have the Boot Camp partition on your old mac, you could use a Windows-based drive image tool, or Winclone. Mounting the image on OS X does not mean that it can be restored on your Boot Camp partition. I think this is because the filesystem on your image is different from the filesystem on your old Boot Camp partition.

Answer (score 1):

I found this here: http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-997823.html
It sounds like it might be what you're experiencing.

> After analyzing and trying things
>   out, I was able to solve this. It
>   seems that Boot Camp does not flag the
>   partition as ACTIVE immediately after
>   Boot Camp creates the new partition
>   from windows.
>
> Assuming you already have a .dmg image
>   of your previous Windows Boot Camp
>   partition, do the following:
>
> 1. Use Boot Camp to allocate the new
>      space. Don't use Disk Utility because
>      the MBR will not be configured
>      properly
> 2. Use Disk Utility to restore your
>      .dmg image to the new Boot Camp
>      partition you just created. Be sure to
>      run IMAGES --> SCAN IMAGE FOR RESTORE
>      in Disk Utility before restoring. You
>      may need to unmount the Boot Camp
>      partition in Disk Utility before it
>      begins to restore.
> 3. Use fdisk in Terminal to mark the
>      Boot Camp partition active. First,
>      enter the fdisk MBR edit mode by
>      running the following:
>
>    ```
>    $sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk0
>    ```
>
>    Ignore the error "could not open MBR
>      file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No
>      such file or directory". Then,
>      determine which partition number to
>      mark active by running the following
>      (*in bold*):
>
>    ```
>    fdisk: 1> show
>    ```
>
>    Your windows partition should be #3
>      labeled "Win95 FAT-32". Now, mark the
>      partition active:
>
>    ```
>    fdisk: 1> flag 3
>    Partition 3 marked active.
>    fdisk:*1> write
>    Device could not be accessed exclusively.
>    A reboot will be needed for changes to take effect. OK? [n] y
>    Writing MBR at offset 0.
>    fdisk: 1> exit
>    ```
>
> Now, reboot and hold the OPTION key
>   and Windows should be listed as a
>   bootable option.

Comment: Unfortunately step 2 is where I am getting the error. "Scan Image for Restore" works fine and then when I try to run the actual restore using disk utility I get the broken pipe error.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your energy saver settings and select Computer Sleep (NEVER) and Uncheck the box that allows it to sleep hard disks. This is why you get a broken pipe because the CPU and disk shutdown mid-restore when you leave it idle.